# How to pass accented characters from JavaScript to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript I create a string which has accented characters such as 'ò' or 'à', e.g. "ò à"

I seem to be unable to create text nodes in html which show the accented characters: if i pass them directly, i get "white question mark in black rhombus"; if i replace the accented characters by the corresponding html entities, i get the entities printed verbatim.
This function

```
function showAccents() {
  s1="ò à";
  s2 = s1.replace(/ò/, "&ograve;").replace(/à/, "&agrave");;
  var eD = document.getElementById("accent1");
  var eHT1 = document.createTextNode(s1);
  var eHT2 = document.createTextNode(s2);
  eD.appendChild(eHT1);
  eD.appendChild(eHT2);
}
```

Produces the following text:

> � �ò &agrave

How do I have to convert the string to get accented characters in HTML?

Comment: Sounds like you are simply missing a page encoding in your HTML.

Comment: `&agrave;` firstly, missing semi colon

Answer (score 9):

You are probably missing a page encoding. Make sure your HTML includes either this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Or this (HTML5):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**EDIT**

It now seems that the problem is the encoding of your Javascript file. It too needs to be Unicode (encoded as UTF8 for example), as if it is saved in a non-Unicode encoding you are likely to have ò and à misinterpreted by the browser which might read these with a different encoding. Just open it in a text editor and save it as UTF8 (doing so will include a BOM at the start of the file that will specify its encoding, solving the problem)

Comment: What result do you get when you use the W3C markup validation service at http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-validator-charset-check.en ?

Comment: i get "encoding:utf-8" and "Content-Type:application/xhtml+xml" and "Doctype:XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0"

Comment: The encoding seems ok: when i directly type "&ograve;" in my xhtml source, the correct accented letter is displayed. Perhaps a different question would be how to pass an entity of the above form from JS to html so it is shown correctly.

Comment: Weird. You shouldn't have such problems, Unicode strings are OK in Javascript. Is this code in a .js file, and if so is the .js file saved in UTF8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, the javascript is in a .js file, which i wrote with xemacs. When i open my file with a notepad-application, it says the encoding is ISO-8859-1. But when i write a html-file containing special characters (not entities) the Browser also displays them correctly.

Comment: OK, that's your problem. You need to open your js file in an editor and save it in UTF8. Edited my answer to explain this.

Comment: I'm using backtick character to create a template and my file is encoded to UTF-8... The problem remains even though I've added the proper charset in `<meta>` and in `<script>` tags

Answer (score 4):

It turned out my xemacs encodes with ISO-8859-1; the current version can not be easily set to UTF-8.

The solution was to change the encoding info from "utf-8" to "iso-8859-1"  in the xhtml's header:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>  
  <meta name="http-equiv" content="Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-88591"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/conjutils.js" charset="iso-8859-1" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xmlutils.js" charset="iso-8859-1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/conjugation.css" />    
  <title>Conjugation</title>

</head>
```

Now i can set a string to 'àò' in my js file, and the browser will display it correctly.

Comment: This solution is Perfect, perfect, perfect!!